# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS - Upgrade to a specific version of previously available GCC version

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, dependencies, gcc, versions

I've added the `ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test` repo for getting the latest GCC-5 version but I had the unfortunate surprise that the available version for 12.04 LTS changed a few days ago from `5.3` to `5.4`. I would like to install the now older 5.3 version. How can I do that?

I've tried to change the version in the `.list` file for vivid but then it complains about unmet dependencies so I think that is not the proper way to do this.

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect you might have to compile GCC 5.1 from source.